# Find legs of a right triangle if radius of circumscribed circle is 15 and radius of inscribed circle is 6

Tags: geometry

Find legs of a right triangle if radius of circumscribed circle is 15 and radius of inscribed circle is 6. That is the example I stumbled upon and i can't manage to solve it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is a right triangle? Do you mean a right angle triangle?

Comment: The radius of circumscribed circle is half the triangle's hypotenuse's length (why?).

Comment: @Thomas http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle

Comment: @DonAntonio What about legs a and b?

Comment: @user27244 By legs, do you mean the two sides that are not the hypotenuse? Also, it would be good if you could describe anything you have tried so far.

Comment: @user27244 Sides a and b (Sides that are not the hypotenuse). 
I tried everything i know. From radius of circumscribed circle i can get C (2R) and i can calculate the Area of triangle ABO (O is the incenter) with formula (C * r) / 2 (the radius of incircle) and I'm stuck there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try labelling a right angled triangle A, B, C, with A as the right angle. BC is 30 because of the well known circle theorem which says the angle in a semicircle is a right angle. Now draw the incircle and label the tangent points as P on AB, Q on BC and R on CA. Observe that AP and RA are both equal to the radius of the incircle.
Let AB be x, and now write down all the lengths of the 4 remaining line segments in terms of x. Now use Pythagoras to form a quadratic in x.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't follow, can you be more detailed?
I don't understand the step where you let AB be x and you write other segments in term of x.

Answer (score 0):

30, 24 and 18, since 30 is the hypotenuse, and the other two are roots of a quadratic you can form and solve by considering a diagram showing the incircle of radius 6, with one of the unknown triangle sides as x

Comment: You might consider showing some details.

Comment: Explanation please?

Answer (score 0):

AP = 6, PB = x-6, but so is BQ because tangents from a single point are equal. Can you continue? You should get CR = 36-x....
Apply pythagoras to the whole triangle.

Comment: Why not ask the question here?

Comment: Sure, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the given clue to the  problem is hard for OP's level of education to understand clearly. Thus, I'd show step by step solution.

Given is $\triangle ABC$, of which, the radius of circumscribed circle is 15 and the radius of inscribed circle is 6. Suppose $A$ is the right angle:

[image: Problem of circle]

If $O$ is the center of the inscribed circle and tangent points of $AB, BC,$ and $CA$ legs are $D,E,$ and $F$, $ADOF$ is a squire with legs equal to $r$, the radius of inscribed circle. Thus, $AD=AF=r=6$.

Let $DB = a$ and $FC = b$. Then, since $\triangle BDO \equiv \triangle BEO$, $BE= BD = a$ and since $\triangle CFO \equiv \triangle CEO$, $EC = CF = b$. However, $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle and hence, the hypotenuse $BC$ is the diameter of circumscribed circle. Thus,
$$a + b = 2R = 30 \tag1$$

If $\angle ACB = \alpha$, Then $AB = BC \sin \alpha$ and $AC = BC \cos \alpha$. Thus:
$$a + 6 = 30 \sin \alpha\tag2$$
$$b + 6 = 30 \cos \alpha\tag3$$

Combining the equations $(1),(2),$ and $(3)$ you'd get:
$$10 \sin \alpha + 10 \cos \alpha = 14 \tag4$$

Solving the equation $(4)$ trignometrically gives you:

$$\sin \alpha = \frac35; \ \sin \alpha = \frac45 \qquad \text{or} \qquad \sin \alpha = \frac45; \ \sin \alpha = \frac35$$

Thus, $AB= 30 \sin \alpha\ = 18$ or $24$ and $AC= 30 \cos \alpha\ = 24$ or $18$.

Therefore, three legs of the triangle is $30,24.$ and $18$.